# How to enable https in ngcordova android

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, https, ngcordova

I am using ngcordova and application is working fine on http mode if i shift to https ios is working fine but android application is not connecting and showing error net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE in console.Is there anything else i need to add.

Comment: try using whitelist plugin `https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-‌​plugin-whitelist/` and allow your domain.  add in your config.xml <access origin="*" />

Comment: Thanks with this i need to write             $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
//            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = 'Content-Type: application/json';
//            delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
            $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
also i app.js

Comment: is it helpful for you?